# TeamCity Rest API "Failed to initialize Spring Context" Error

Tags: java, teamcity

I installed TC on my new pc but ı have some failures. I am getting Failed to "initialize Spring Context" Error after TC installation and TC WebUI is not working properly. I connected db from PostgreSQL and JRE 1.8.0_351 installed.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: TeamCityError]

Error Message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLEndpoint' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/TeamCity/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/plugins/.unpacked/rest-api/server/rest-api.jar!/jetbrains/buildServer/server/graphql/GraphQLEndpoint.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLProvider': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverError: No method or field found as defined in schema <unknown>:282 with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment] as the last argument), in priority order:

jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.resolver.AgentResolver.id(jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.model.Agent)
jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.resolver.AgentResolver.getİd(jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.model.Agent)
jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.resolver.AgentResolver.id
jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.model.Agent.id()
jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.model.Agent.getİd()
jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.model.Agent.id
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at jetbrains.buildServer.plugins.spring.SpringPluginLoader.pluginClassesLoaded(SpringPluginLoader.java:126)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at jetbrains.buildServer.util.EventDispatcher.invokeListeners(EventDispatcher.java:157)
at jetbrains.buildServer.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:136)
at jetbrains.buildServer.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:82)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.pluginClassesLoaded(Unknown Source)
at jetbrains.buildServer.plugins.PluginManagerImpl$5.visitPlugin(PluginManagerImpl.java:441)
at jetbrains.buildServer.plugins.PluginsCollection$1.run(PluginsCollection.java:98)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLProvider': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is graphql.kickstart.tools.resolver.FieldResolverError: No method or field found as defined in schema <unknown>:282 with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment] as the last argument), in priority order:

jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.resolver.AgentResolver.id(jetbrains.buildServer.server.graphql.model.Agent)...
```

Comment: Add error messages as text not as unreadable image

Comment: Okay I added to question.

Comment: nice question. taking a look into it. could you please also fire this bug to jetbrains youtrack?

Comment: which version of TeamCity do you use?

Comment: TeamCity Professional 2022.10.1 (build 116934)

Comment: how it is installed? in docker? @HighHill

Comment: No, in Windows 11